# Não consigo capturar o post pela webapi c#

Tags: javascript, c#, post, asp.net-web-api

bom dia. Já estou tentando a alguns dias tentando capturar um POST feito no JavaScript pela webapi c# e o máximo que conseguir é a webapi me dizendo que o parâmetro esperado está NULL.

```
var objFornecedor = {
                ID_FORNECEDOR: 38,
                NOME: "cleverton teste",
                CNPJ: "546546546546",
                ENDERECO: "rua c",
                BAIRRO: "novo teste",
                CIDADE: "serrinha",
                SITUACAO: "1",
                DATA_CADASTRO: new Date(2015,02,02)
    }


    $.ajax({
                  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: objFornecedor,
          url: 'http://localhost:3190/servicowebapi/fornecedor/incluir',
      success: function(retorno)
        {
              alert('funcionou');..........
```

e aqui eis o códigos que recebe

```
  [HttpPost]
  [ActionName("incluir")]
  public void Post(FORNECEDOR objFornecedor)
  {
      ctx.FORNECEDOR.Add(objFornecedor);
      ctx.SaveChanges();
  }
```

me retorna esse erro.
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Valor não pode ser nulo.
ctx.FORNECEDOR.Add(objFornecedor);
objFornecedor está NULL

e aqui segue minha classe FORNECEDOR

```
public partial class FORNECEDOR
{
    public int ID_FORNECEDOR { get; set; }
    public string NOME { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string ENDERECO { get; set; }
    public string BAIRRO { get; set; }
    public string CIDADE { get; set; }
    public string SITUACAO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DATA_CADASTRO { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use o `JSON.stringify`:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(objFornecedor),
...
```

Comment: já fiz de toda forma que vc imaginar, acabei de testar por uma página ASP.nET com o mesmo código para consumir e adivinha ?  o asp.net consome (jQuery), mas lá por dentro do plugin do cordova só consigo ler.

Comment: já adicionei todos os verbos no WebConfig POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS

Comment: <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />

Comment: @Cleverton, seria legal por na pergunta que está utilizando Cordova. Fiz utilizando uma página ASP.Net e deu no mesmo que você. Se eu encontrar tempo, tento fazer com cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
var objFornecedor = {
        ID_FORNECEDOR: 38,
        NOME: "cleverton teste",
        CNPJ: "546546546546",
        ENDERECO: "rua c",
        BAIRRO: "novo teste",
        CIDADE: "serrinha",
        SITUACAO: "1",
        DATA_CADASTRO: new Date(2015, 02, 02)
    };

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(objFornecedor),
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3190/servicowebapi/fornecedor/incluir',
        success: function (retorno) {
            alert('funcionou');
        }
    });
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3190/servicowebapi/fornecedor/incluir?ID_FORNECEDOR=38&NOM…ATA_CADASTRO=Mon+Mar+02+2015+00%3A00%3A00+GMT-0300+(Hora+oficial+do+Brasil). Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: @Cleverton editei a resposta, tenta com esse código.

Comment: então, a solução temporária foi feita por meio de uma POG, fiz uma solicitação GET, passei pelos URL. não entendo pq usando o HttpPost não funciona.

Comment: Fiz um exemplo com o mesmo código acima e funcionou.

Comment: NÃO SEI o que acontece, se eu colocar o verbo HttpPost na webapi não funciona